# Search of an input string in spreadsheet

Tags: excel, openxml, spreadsheet

I am using the Open XML SDK to open an Excel file (xlsx) and I want to find a specific string or integer passed from outside to check for duplicates of the value in the spreadsheet.

How can I search for the input string in all the cells of spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Book1.xlsx", true))
            {
                Sheet sheet = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First<Sheet>();
                Worksheet worksheet = ((WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id)).Worksheet;
                IEnumerable<Row> allRows = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Descendants<Row>();
                foreach (Row currentRow in allRows)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Cell> allCells = currentRow.Descendants<Cell>();
                    foreach (Cell currentCell in allCells)
                    {
                        CellValue currentCellValue = currentCell.GetFirstChild<CellValue>();
                        string data = null;
                        if (currentCell.DataType != null)
                        {
                            if (currentCell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString) // cell has a cell value that is a string, thus, stored else where
                            {
                                data = document.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault().SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(currentCellValue.Text)).InnerText;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data = currentCellValue.Text;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(data);

                        /* 
                            your code here

                                if(data.contains("myText"))
                                    doSomething();

                        */

                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.wud like to know what will happen if the string written in excel doesn't exists in SharedStringTable table.Data type of the cell value is of string type not sharedstring type.Then how can I retrieve the cell value from excel to proceed for search.