# Search string in excel file and return searched cell's rowindex and columnindex using OpenXML in C#

Tags: c#, openxml

I want to search string in excel file, I used to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in my program and It works perfectly. I use this code below:

```
 findRange1 = range1.Find("apple", LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole);
```

However, I faced a problem using interop excel in the server side. And I change my program using OpenXML. I want to do the searching method as well using OpenXML. how to do it in OpenXML?

Comment: Interop can be slow. Why dont you convert your excel to C# List<class> using OpenXML and then use linq on it to search the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search of an input string in spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197881/search-of-an-input-string-in-spreadsheet)

Comment: @AccessDenied i want to search for the range

Comment: the `range` contains array of strings or any else? or which type of string do you want to search?

Comment: suppose i want to search fro "apple". find the cell contain text "apple" in column B, and give me the cell range as result.for ex: [1,2]

Comment: did u successfully load you excel sheet to `WorkbookPart` of open xml or you need that code too.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? The to OpenXML part or the search part?

Comment: I need them too.

Comment: in search part I am confused.

Comment: yes let me prepare answer for you

Comment: you want to search particular string in any cell in excel sheet and return its index for example your `apple` string is in row 23 and column 12 so you want this cell index like [23,12]  right?

Comment: yes, it is what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**  Import your excel document `.xlsx` or `xls` to `SpreadsheetDocument` of `OpenXMl`.

```
public WorkbookPart ImportExcel()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = @"your path to excel document";

            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                MemoryStream m_ms = new MemoryStream();
                fs.CopyTo(m_ms);

                SpreadsheetDocument m_Doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(m_ms, false);

                return m_Doc.WorkbookPart;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**2)** Create method to get index in the form of `[row, column]` by using specific search criteria.

```
public string GetIndexBySearch(string search)
        {

            WorkbookPart workbookPart = ImportExcel();
            var sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>();
            Sheet sheet = sheets.Where(x => x.Name.Value == "you sheet name in excel document").FirstOrDefault();

            string index = string.Empty;

            if (sheet != null)
            {
                var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
                var rows = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().ToList();

                // Remove the header row
                rows.RemoveAt(0);

                foreach (var row in rows)
                {
                    var cellss = row.Elements<Cell>().ToList();

                    foreach (var cell in cellss)
                    {
                        var value = cell.InnerText;
                        var stringTable = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();
                        value = stringTable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                        bool isFound = value.Trim().ToLower().Contains(search.Trim().ToLower());

                        if (isFound)
                        {
                            index = $"[{row.RowIndex}, {GetColumnIndex(cell.CellReference)}]";
                            return index;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            return index;
        }
```

**3)** Finally this method gives you column index by passing column name.

```
private static int? GetColumnIndex(string cellReference)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellReference))
        {
            return null;
        }

        string columnReference = Regex.Replace(cellReference.ToUpper(), @"[\d]", string.Empty);

        int columnNumber = -1;
        int mulitplier = 1;

        foreach (char c in columnReference.ToCharArray().Reverse())
        {
            columnNumber += mulitplier * ((int)c - 64);

            mulitplier = mulitplier * 26;
        }

        return columnNumber + 1;
    }
```

**4)** Considering all above 3 methods are in same class called `MyClass`. Then you will use `GetIndexBySearch` like

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
string index = c.GetIndexBySearch("AFL");
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @raspi surya, view the answer might be it help you :) just enter your search string instead of `AFL`.